# Vector tiles with Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a bunch of very large polygons that I'd like to overlay on my Google map. I have a tile server that serves GeoJSON features, and which also takes care of the various geometric operations I need to make the app work (joining polygons, simplification to zoom level, tiling, etc).

At present, we're just displaying the large polygons on the map as data layers, but ideally we'd be able to display simplified versions of the polygons at lesser zoom levels and increase their complexity inline with zoom level.

My options seem to be:

**1) Data Layers**: hook into the various map change events and then add/remove from the map as appropriate (where adding would be fetching the appropriate tile). Difficulty here would be that there seem to be a lot of map change events and finding the smoothest way to achieve could take considerable effort. Plus, it feels as though I'm working against the data API here.

**2) OverlayView**: similar to the above, but as an absolute sized OverlayView (i.e. a full covering). The thinking would be that the overlay would listen to draw events, fetch the appropriate tile, and add/clean-up as required. This seems like it'd be a more predictable solution, but again there's a lot to it.

I don't know enough about how maps works under-the-hood to provide much more insight, but my eventual solution (in so much as it helps) would be something that takes a tile server URL and then fits as smoothly as possible into how maps works to load the right tile, for the right zoom level (and given they're vector tiles, I could possibly also progressively enhance/degrade as zoom levels or position changed).

Can anyone shed any insight? How would you approach it?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to pull off. But have you thought about KML Layer? It works as a TileOverlay, yet when there is large data it is rather optimized. You can go through the documentation and see if its something that can work for your project. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#kml_layer_options

Comment: I have built a solution for rendering mapbox vector tiles on google maps.  I am in the process of opensourcing the whole thing, but for now you can see the core part that does the rendering https://landtechnologies.github.io/Mapbox-vector-tiles-basic-js-renderer/debug/basic/ ...then it's a case of doing something like that suggested by amenadiel.

Answer (score 7):

The way I've come to deal with the idea of fetching tiled data is by using overlayMapTypes. [Here's a working example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-overlay).

Just as any object implementing the [MapType interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapType), it expects you to define a `getTile` method and, optionally, a `releaseTile` method.

Whenever a tile enters the viewport, this kind of object calls `getTile` passing it the coords and zoom. Whenever a tile exits the viewport, it calls `releaseTile` with the node element that it's being removed. So, using the linked example, you just need to add a Data Layer to each tile, and remove it when the tile is released:

Let's say your tile serving backend answers to an url like

```
'/mytiles/1048/1520/13';
```

Then (borrowing almost the complete code for the example) you would declare the overlayMapType as

```
function CoordMapType() {
    this.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256, 256);
}

CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function (coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
    var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div'),
        tileUrl = '/mytiles/' + coord.x + '/' + coord.y + '/' + zoom;

    div.innerHTML = coord;
    div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
    div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
    div.style.fontSize = '10';
    div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
    div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';

    div.dataLayer = new google.maps.Data();


    div.dataLayer.loadGeoJson(tileUrl,null, function() {
        div.dataLayer.setMap(map);
    });

    return div;
};

CoordMapType.prototype.releaseTile = function (tile) {
    if (tile.dataLayer) {
        tile.dataLayer.setMap(null);
    }
};


map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType());
```

Comment: could you please show how to render tiles if they are not in json format but pbf instead?

Comment: it's been a while since I developed in Google Maps, but I don't think there is any effort in place to add any kind of vector tiles support, much less protobuf.

Answer (score 7):

I have just open-sourced a fork of mapbox-gl-js which lets you render vector tiles on the client in a controlled way, in particular this means you can use vector tiles on top of a google map.

A live demo is [here](https://landtechnologies.github.io/Mapbox-vector-tiles-basic-js-renderer/debug/basic/google), and the documention/code is [here](https://github.com/landtechnologies/Mapbox-vector-tiles-basic-js-renderer)

Here is open streetmap tiles on top of a google satellite image...

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you so much for this! For anyone trying to get a pbf to show on a google map, this is it!

For the available zooms variable, I see it can be an array, but the code seems to only check the first element. is there any advantage to specifying multiple items in that array? Again, thank you!

Comment: nevermind about the "only checking the first element" ... that was my doing while playing around with it, and I forgot hahaha

Answer (score 2):

Another option to the already mentioned ones is using *deck.gl*, in specific the following component, which works pretty well for vector tiles and is compatible with Gooogle Maps (you don't have to use Mapbox):

https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/mvt-layer

Comment: I followed this route and indeed got my vector tiles loading on a google map. However the deck.gl MVTLayer does not support the MVT styling spec, so if you're using an MVT-based vector tile service, this is not an option :(

Comment: Worth noting though - this is an excellent solution if your tiles only need simple or consistent styling, as you can style features yourself with the deck.gl library. In the end, this is the best solution I have found. Nice summary of the google-maps / deck.gl integration here: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/richer-data-visualization-google-maps-platform-using-deckgl

Answer (score 1):

I have recently created a library to load vector tiles in Google Maps using the overlayMapType object. Add the .pbf url like this:

```
var options = {
    url: "http://your_vector_tiles_url/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
};

var mvtSource = new MVTSource(map, options);
map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, mvtSource);
```

Link to the [Vector Tiles Google Maps](https://github.com/techjb/Vector-Tiles-Google-Maps) library and a [working example](https://techjb.github.io/Vector-Tiles-Google-Maps/examples/basic.html).